# the content of git lab cicd file to just do a simple pull

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have installed gitlab runner on my server and connected that to my gitlab . now i want to know what should i write in my `.gitlab.ci.yml` just to simply pull the project when even i push some commits on master (i dont need to build any thing or update composer just pull and push) . i ask this because when i have configured the jobs they use to work for some commits but now they are passing but the project on my server is not being updated . here is my gitlab file content :

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# To contribute improvements to CI/CD templates, please follow the Development guide at:
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html
# This specific template is located at:
# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Getting-Started.gitlab-ci.yml

# This is a sample GitLab CI/CD configuration file that should run without any modifications.
# It demonstrates a basic 3 stage CI/CD pipeline. Instead of real tests or scripts,
# it uses echo commands to simulate the pipeline execution.
#
# A pipeline is composed of independent jobs that run scripts, grouped into stages.
# Stages run in sequential order, but jobs within stages run in parallel.
#
# For more information, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#stages

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "Code coverage is 90%"

lint-test-job:   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "No lint issues found."

deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

note that my project is a laravel project if it makes some changes  . thanks in advance

Comment: `just to simply pull the project when even i push some commits` The runner pulls the commit it runs on automatically to the context of the runner, it's already there.

Comment: then i have to debug why its not doing this how can i do that can u help in this case ?

Comment: `why its not doing this` How do you check it? What type of runner did you register?

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual pipeline definition instead of just the `echo`'s? There's not enough information here for us to answer with anything helpful.